# Cannot lock an unsaved transient instance, when I am using session.lock

Tags: java, hibernate

Below is my peaces of code

```
 public ATMRecord store(ATMRecord atmRecord) {
    Session session = HibernateUtility.getSession();
    try {
        Transaction tx = HibernateUtility.beginTransaction(session);
        logger.info("saving an ATMRecord[" + atmRecord + "]");
        try {

            session.lock(atmRecord, LockMode.UPGRADE);
            session.merge(atmRecord);
        } catch (Throwable e) {
                            e.prinstacktrace());
            return null;
        }
        HibernateUtility.commitTransaction(tx, session);
        return record;
    } finally {
        HibernateUtility.closeSession(session);
    }
```

While I am trying save ATMRecord object I am facing below exception
org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: cannot lock an unsaved transient instance.
ATMRecord is simple pojo object and represent a row (not implemented serialized in the current code). There is no joins or complex mappings related to this.
How can I overcome the above issue.
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. The `lock()` call will lock the row in the database. You're trying to lock a transient object, meaning that Hibernate doesn't even know if the object *has* a corresponding row in the database or not.

Comment: Thanks for quick response, the main reason I am using the lock on a row is we are facing stalestate exception(data modified.deleted by other thread). So I have to keep sync between ATMRecord and corresponding row. So how can I use lock in this case

Comment: Consider optimistic locking or lock it when you *fetch* it. If you don't understand how those work, have someone do it who does. You don't want to cause deadlocks.

Comment: Thanks for the valuable suggestion, I will leave it to others, who can do better. I don't want cause any performance issues